# Connecting to remote MAC via SSH tunnelling over VPN

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

From my laptop, I am trying to open remote desktop in server2:

This is how it looks like:

```
my-mac-laptop -> vpn. ---> server1(redhat)  ->  server2(mac-server)
                           <----------same network--------------->
```

Here, I can't access `server2` directly. I have to connect to `server1` via VPN. And from `server1` I can access `server2(mac-server)`.

I have already enabled *Remote Login* and *Remote Management* in the `server2(mac-server)`.

Followed to that, I am attempting to port forward the remote desktop ports with the following command:

```
ssh -L 5900:server2-ip-address:5900 user@server1
```

My understanding has been this will tunnel all the remote desktop traffic to the `server2(mac-server)` in my `mac laptop`.

In the next step, I open `screen-sharing app` from my mac laptop and type `localhost` which should forward 5900 traffic to `mac-server2` over the `ssh-tunnel`.

I even get the following prompt which means the port forwarding is happening:

`Screen Sharing requires a user name and password to sign in to 127.0.0.1:5900.`

Followed to that, I give the user name and password and then it loops for a long time standing "Connecting..." and eventually fails.

I am wondering whether there is logging somewhere that I can check to triage this issue.

I would like to know how I can triage this case, any ideas welcome.

Are there logs in the `mac-server2` that might assist me to debug?

Comment: IIRC the Screen Sharing app does something a little weird when connecting to localhost. When I do this, I use port 5901 instead (i.e. `ssh -L 5901:server2-ip-address:5900 ...`, then from the Finder do View menu > Connect to Server (Command-K), and connect to `vnc://127.0.0.1:5901`. I'm not sure all that's necessary, but it works for me.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the pointer. I just attempted with the above steps and get the same issue. I get the prompt ""Screen Sharing requires a user name and password to sign in to 127.0.0.1:5901." and then I give the user:pass and then it gets stuck.